# C#Windowsフォームアプリにおいて非同期でSQL Serverへの読み書きを行う場合のベストプラクティス

Tags: c#, sql-server, 非同期

シリアルポートでの受信結果をSQL Serverへ書き込む仕組みを検討しています
書き込みの間も受信やUIを止められないので非同期での書き込みが必要かと考えました

非同期処理について調べたところasync/awaitを使ったTaskクラスによる実装が見つかりますが、これは非同期処理が終了したらTaskが終了すると理解しています。

これに対して、調べる前のイメージは、DBへアクセスするスレッドが常に存在し、シリアルポートからの受信に応じてDBアクセススレッドへ向かってキューイングするイメージでいたのですが、近年はそのような仕組みは推奨されていないのでしょうか？

「C#　並行処理」などで検索したのですが、DBアクセスするスレッドやプロセスが常に存在するような仕組みは見当たりませんでした。（Taskを使った例は見つかります）

一般的なよくある設計がわからないので、抽象的な質問かと思いますがご教示いただければと思います。

（追記）

> SqlCommand等のDB関連クラスには標準で非同期処理用のメソッド

EntityFrameworkを利用したSQL Serverへのアクセスを行いたいと思っています。

（追記21/10/19）
非同期という書き方が余計だったかもしれません。
10数年前のUnixサーバでの記憶ですが、DBアクセスするプロセスを1つ用意し、これにエンキューする仕組みとすることで、その他の処理をブロックせず、要求の順序を維持し、また、DBへの同時アクセスを予防するという設計がありました。
検索したところ、これに似た仕組みはC#では一般的でないように思われました。
それならば、ベストプラクティスというか一般的な設計はどのようなものか有識者に教えていただきたいと考え投稿しました。

Comment: 今回の質問の主題よりも、もしシリアルポート系処理が重い/大きい/頻度が高い/即応性が必要な場合には、むしろそちらをどうするか検討した方が良いかもしれませんね。

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます。
もとの投稿には書けていませんが、シリアルポートは頻度の低い受信で、ほぼほぼ既存設計の流用になると見込んでいるため、経験も少なくスキルが低いDB関連の方が不安に思っています。
受信頻度が低いのでキューイングの仕組みは無くてもいいのか？とかそういうレベルです……

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DBアクセスするスレッドやプロセスが常に存在するような仕組みは見当たりませんでした。

質問者さんの言う「仕組み」は以下の記事の図にある Thread を使うものですよね？ 違います？

https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/fdotnet/chushin/masterasync_01/masterasync_01_02.html

であれば、今は ThreadPool を利用した async / awat を使うのが主流です。理由は紹介した記事に書いてあるので読んでください。

EF Core を使うなら、radian さんの回答のコメントで質問者さんが調べた DbContext.SaveChangesAsync で可能です。

> 書き込みの間も受信やUIを止められないので非同期での書き込みが必要かと考えました

そこのところですが、Tread を使う ThreadPool を使うどちらにせよ、UI スレッドとパラレルに実行されるわけではないのはご存じですか？

シングル CPU/コアですと、以下の記事の一番下の図の (2) になります。

https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/spv/0503/12/news025.html

Comment: >今は ThreadPool を利用した async / awat を使うのが主流です。理由は紹介した記事に　　       


紹介いただいた記事にあった、マルチスレッドの一般的なデメリットは読みました。async/awaitとの比較は無かったようなので、どの点で有利不利なのかはわかりませんでした。　　         


近年はasync/awaitを使うのが主流とのことなので、DBアクセスを担う機能（スレッドやプロセス）が常に存在するような設計は主流ではないと受け取りました。

Comment: 「パラレルに実行」については「時分割で並行して動くように見える」と理解しています

Comment: 最初の回答でリンクを間違えて張ってしまったのですが、訂正したのでそちらを読んでください。

Comment: Thread を使う場合のデメリットを、紹介した記事から抜粋しておくと "そして何よりも問題なのは、開発者がスレッドというものを直接意識し、生成・管理・破棄しなければならないことだ。このような極めてシステム寄りな事象について思案しなければならないのは、コーディングにおいて大いなる雑念でしかない。可能ならば隠ぺいし、書きたい処理だけに集中したいものだ。" です。

Comment: レスポンスありがとうございます。  
スレッドを1つ用意しておくという設計思想？が古いようにも思われます。  
リンクの記事も第1回以降も読んでみます。

Comment: Microsoft ドキュメント (元は MSDN Blog の記事) https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/archive/blogs/tmarq/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications で、Thread を使うことに言及していて、自分的に興味深かったのでご参考に紹介しておきます。その記事の FAQ の 4 番目に書いてありますが、その記事を書いた Microsoft の開発者よりはるかにスマートに実装できるのでなければ Thread を使うのは "don't even think about it" だそうです。理由も書いてありますが、以下に概略を書いておきます（誤訳はあるかも）。(1) CLR ThreadPool を使用するのに比べて非常にコストが高い。(2) 自分で作った Thread に I/O 要求が残ってないか終了前にチェックしなければならない。(3) システムのパフォーマンスを保つには実行されている Thread の数が適切でなければならないが、自分で Thread を作るのであればパフォーマンスを保つのは自分の責任になる。

Comment: 結局、非同期でDBに書き込みたいというのが目的で、それをより少ないコーディングで実現するであれば、既に多くの人が利用していて十分に実績があるであろう標準の非同期処理を用いるべきです。わざわざ自前でスレッド処理やキューイング処理をコーディングして、コード量やテストを増やす必要は無いのではないかと。

Comment: これはDB更新だけではなく、シリアルポートの方も非同期処理にしないと、むなかたさんの要望は実現できないのではないでしょうか？単にDB書き込みをawaitで待っていてもスレッドを無駄に消費しないだけだと思いますが…。

Answer (score 0):

> これに対して、調べる前のイメージは、DBへアクセスするスレッドが常に存在し、シリアルポートからの受信に応じてDBアクセススレッドへ向かってキューイングするイメージでいたのですが、近年はそのような仕組みは推奨されていないのでしょうか？

SqlConnection、SqlCommand等のDB関連クラスには標準で非同期処理用のメソッド（末尾がAsyncのもの）があるので、わざわざそのような事はしないのではないでしょうか。
非同期処理そのものが判らないということであれば、そちらの学習から入ったほうが近道になると思います。
[async および await を使用した非同期プログラミング](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
もとの投稿にも追記しましたがEntityFrameworkを予定していたためにDB関連クラスについては調べていませんでした。
ご案内いただいたページは調査する際に見たことがありましたが、タスクが終了する前提の解説だったため、疑問は消えませんでした。

Comment: EntityFrameworkにも非同期用のメソッドはあると思いますよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の非同期用のメソッドありますね。調べてみます。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/core/miscellaneous/async